# Why the transition property is not working in this case?

Tags: css, transition

```css
.pic{
 position: relative;
}

.pic .texthover{
 position: absolute;
 bottom:3%;
 display: none;
 z-index: 8000;
 margin: 0 0 3.2px 0;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 5px;
 background: rgba(213,12,16,1.00);
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 transition: all 2s ease;
}



.pic:hover .texthover{
 display: block;
 
   
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-images">
    <li>
     <a href="#">
     <div class="pic">
     <img src="1 escultura.fw.png" width="278" height="175" title="Esculturas del Prado"                       class="image"/>
     
      <div class="hover" style="">
       <p class="texthover">  Escultura neoclasicista hasta el XVII</p>
      </div> <!--END DIV HOVER-->
     </div> <!--END DIV PIC-->
     
    
    </li>
```

I've been racking my brain over this, it must be a very simple detail that escapes my comprehension, can anybody point it out??? Thanks all. I put the transition property in the original element and still not working...

Comment: Do you want a transition from display:none to display:block?? Simply you can't! This is the list of property you can animate: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp. You could use opacity instead, from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

A Vanila Example of Transition and how it works. You can change as per requirements.

```css
div.list-images a:hover {
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s linear; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s linear; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s linear; /* Opera */
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s linear; /* Explorer 10 */
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-images"><a href="#" id="ctudeal">transition</a></div>
```

Comment: It's not the answer I needed, I know  that simple rule, it's about that specific example I posted. Thanks anyway mate.